# Can I install windows 10 in windows 8 laptop using the same product key

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-installation, product-key

I have laptop that come with windows 8 installed and I install windows 10 on the same hard drive (in new partition) using same product key.

I want to keep windows 8 and don't want to use windows 10 right now but I install it to get free upgrade before 29/07/2016 (the last day for free upgrade)

my question is : is that ok or my product key will be blocked.

NOTE:

- Now both windows are activated
- Original windows 8 is Single Language OEM
- I install windows 10 using bootable flash drive that I made it by Media Creation Tool downloaded from Microsoft site.

Comment: At any given time you are only allowed to have Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 installed on the machine.  If you have both installed then you are in violation of EULA.

Comment: @Ramhound, Thank You, I think I will reset my laptop to its original Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the free upgrade system (via Windows Update, Media Creation Tool or standalone installation media), Windows 10 will overwrite your Windows 8. It is the purpose of an *upgrade*: it replaces what already exists with something newer.

However, you will still be allowed to install and activate Windows 10 with a Windows 8 key. However, you won't be legally permitted to have both Windows 8 and 10 installed (even if they are not used) with the same key at the same time. And IIRC, you are not even allowed to permform a clean install with an OEM key.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan, so now I have to delete one windows 10. can i then install windows 10 using windows 8 key after 29/07/2016.

Comment: Your key will still be valid after 29/07. If you perform a clean install *or* an upgrade from a regular installation media (a Windows 10 DVD) you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: I'm Sorry @Nathan but in your answer you said `you are not even allowed to permform a clean install with an OEM key` and in comments you said that I can if I have `regular installation media (a Windows 10 DVD) `. I install windows 10 using bootable flash drive that I made it by Media Creation Tool . is my flash drive is regular installation media?. I edit my question to add this.

Comment: What I meant was, Windows will let you *upgrade* your installation from Windows 8 to 10. Past 29/07, you won't be able to download it from Microsoft Update, and you will need an installation media. If you wish to upgrade, then a USB key from Media Creation Tool will work. Obviously you have to make sure nobody will erase the contents of that key between 29/07 and the moment you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan,its clear now and you answer my question but I have new question and  I know from StackOverflow that asking questions in comments is not good way so i will post new question.

Comment: I post new question : [Can I use windows 10 installation media that I made by Media Creation Tool to install in another computer](http://superuser.com/questions/1100405/can-i-use-windows-10-installation-media-that-i-made-by-media-creation-tool-to-in)

Comment: "you won't be able to download it from Microsoft Update" - How exactly do you know that?

Comment: @Ramhound Because they anounced on their website that support for free upgrade to WIn10 will end on July 29th.

Comment: @NathanShiraini - That does not mean it won't be possible to upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows Update, it just means, once installed you will have to purchase a Windows 10 key digitally from the Microsoft Store(which can already be done today and has been done for the last year).