# Can I use windows 10 installation media that I made by Media Creation Tool to install in another computer

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-installation, product-key

I have made bootable flash drive using Media Creation Tool (Windows 10 Single Language) from laptop that have activated Windows 8 to use it for upgrade or clean install later.

my question is: can I use this flash drive to install Windows 10 in another laptop using its own product key (product key that saved in BIOS), or this media (flash drive) contain the product key of the Windows 8 where Media Creation Tool was run.

Edit:

I use this flash drive to install windows 10 on other 2 laptops and both are activated but when I use Nirsoft ProduKey to see the product key, I see that both have the same Windows 10 Key and this key is not the same as the original Windows 8 key (product key that saved in BIOS)

and in the first laptop (the one that I use to download and run Media Creation Tool) the Key of windows 10 is same as the key that saved in BIOS.

So now I have 2 laptops with same Windows 10 key, I'm not sure if this is OK or this Key will be block later.

Note: all 3 laptops came with windows 8 Single Language installd and I didn't enter any key when install windows 10 I just click `Skip` when setup ask for Product Key.

Comment: If the .ISO is for `Windows 10 Home Single Language` then it can only upgrade a machine running `Windows 8.1 Home Single Language`.  Since you are performing an upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, before July 29th, you won't need to or even be prompted to enter a product key at any point.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, yes all 3 laptops are Windows 8 Single Language and I'm sorry because I lose internet connection when i was trying to edit my question, the problem is that now I have 2 laptops with same Windows 10 key.

Comment: if they came with Windows 8.1, they actually are not, all Windows 10 machines upgraded from a previous version of Windows has the same generic key. Don't worry about what key is being claimed, since your have an OEM license, your not actually viewing the correct key.

Comment: @Ramhound, Thank you very much, the important point for me is now clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the flash drive to install Windows 10 on any machine.  The Windows 10 installation will ask/search for a key.

Comment: Sorry @Keltari , but I lose internet connection when i was trying to edit my question, I use this flash drive to install windows 10 in another 2 laptops and now both have the same windows 10 Key, is this normal and OK or I do something wrong.

Comment: Its ok, don't worry key will be automatically used when connected to the internet.